# Generic form validation using a class for input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Hi there I wonder if you could assist me with some information on the following topic: I would like to create a generic form validation class with javascript 
and assign my input fields the appropriate class name to do the validation check on.

How can I accomplish this?
My Input:

```
<input type="text" class="alphabeticalValidation" name="Vvehicle"/>
```

My Validation code:

```
    function fieldValadation() {
    var errMsg = "";
    var isNumber = $(".numericalValidation");
    var isWord = $(".alphabeticalValidation");
    var regex0 = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var regexA = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    // check to see if fields are not empty - if so test the data type
    if (isNumber.length != 0 && isWord.length != 0 ) {


        if (isNumber != regex0) {
            errMsg += "Field can only contain numerical charaters \n"
        }
        if (isWord != regexA) {
            errMsg += "Field can only contain alphabetical characters \n"
        }
    }
    else {
        errMsg += "Fields cannot be empty \n";   
    }
    return errMsg;
}
```

Comment: Use `RegExp#test` to check if a string is in the pattern.

Comment: would that work the same with a class so somthing like RegExp(.test) could you provide a example?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @Tushar ,Dosen't seem that it will work for what i need unfortunately because im using a class it seems to be difficult to test with regex, I have also tried isNan which seems to get me closer but then weather i have a value in the field or not it displays the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my query by adding `.val()` after calling the class keeps it generic meaning I can assign the class to multiple input fields that should validate a certain criteria.

```
function fieldValadation() {

    var errmsg = '';    
    var Vehicle = $(".alphabeticalValidation").val();
    var isNumber = $(".numericalValidation").val();

    if (Vehicle != "" && isNumber != "") {
        if (!isNaN(Vehicle)) {
            errmsg += "Field can only contain letters \n";
        }
        if (isNaN(isNumber)) {
            errmsg += "Field can only contain numbers \n";
        }
    }
    else {
        errmsg += "Field cannot be empty \n";
    }

    return errmsg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by making the validation with class. all you need to do just update your code like below -

```
$(".numericalValidation").each(function(){
    var isNumber = $(this).val();
    var errMsg = '';
    if (isNumber.length != 0 && isWord.length != 0 ) {
        if (isNumber != regex0) {
            errMsg = "Field can only contain numerical charaters \n"
        }
        if (isWord != regexA) {
            errMsg = "Field can only contain alphabetical characters \n"
        }
    }
    else {
        errMsg = "Fields cannot be empty \n";   
    }
    $(this).parent().find('label').html(errMsg);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you but does not work for my application unfortunately but will work great if you only validating one form with this. for my use multiple forms should be able to use the same js file to validate.